# ethzasl_ptam + Kinetic input image problem

Tags: ros, ethzasl-ptam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

Here below is a capture from usb_cam/image_raw and the same picture but from ethzasl_ptam calibrator

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

I'm using ROS kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04 and modified ethzasl_ptam to compile it with opencv3.

Any guess ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239342/ethzasl_ptam-+-kinetic-input-image-problem/) by [Rouno](https://answers.ros.org/users/4024/rouno/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2016-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok so I was giving the wrong image format. Giving a mono image through image_proc solved the issue _

---

Originally posted by [Rouno](https://answers.ros.org/users/4024/rouno/) with karma: 68 on 2016-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0